# magento 2.3.1 Store redirect based on Geo IP

Tags: magento2, store-switcher, geoip

I want to redirect user to a specific store based on IP address. I am using front controller dispatch method. i have overridden this method through plugin and using before dispatch method.

I am also using controller_action_predispatch event in observer as well. First user is getting redirect to correct store but next user is getting cached page. controller_action_predispatch event is not firing.

How to redirect second user to a correct store and how to prevent cached page getting served to second user onwards.

Here is my switcher plugin,

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface">
    <plugin name="custom_store_switcher"
            type="Companyname\Customredirect\Plugin\Switcher"
    />
</type>
```

```
class Switcher
{
    /**
     * @var \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer
     */
    private $geoIpHelperCustomer;

    /**
     * @var \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher
     */
    private $modelSwitcher;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    private $response;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $storeRepository;

    /**
     * Switcher constructor.
     *
     * @param \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer $geoIpHelperCustomer
     * @param \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher $modelSwitcher
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
     * @param \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer $geoIpHelperCustomer,
        \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher $modelSwitcher,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
        \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
    ) {
        $this->geoIpHelperCustomer = $geoIpHelperCustomer;
        $this->modelSwitcher       = $modelSwitcher;
        $this->response            = $response;
        $this->storeRepository     = $storeRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieSizeLimitReachedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {


        if (!$this->modelSwitcher->isAllowed($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $customerStoreCode = $this->modelSwitcher->getCustomerStoreCode();
        if (!$customerStoreCode) {
            return;
        }

        $storeCookie = $this->geoIpHelperCustomer->getCookie('geoip_store_code');

        if (!$storeCookie || $request->getParam('geoip_country', false)) {
            try {
                /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store */
                $store = $this->storeRepository->get($customerStoreCode);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return;
            }
            setcookie('geoip_store_code', $customerStoreCode, time() + $this->geoIpHelperCustomer->getCookieLifetime());
            setcookie('geoip_test_0', '3', time() + 100);
            setcookie('store', $customerStoreCode, time() + 86400);
            $params = $request->getParams();

            if (empty($params)) {
                $params['_query'] = ['___store' => $customerStoreCode];
            } else {
                $params['_query']['___store'] = $customerStoreCode;
            }

            $this->response->setRedirect($store->getUrl('', $params));

            return;
        } elseif ($request->getParam('___store', false)) {
            $requestStore = $request->getParam('___store', false);
            setcookie('geoip_store_code', $requestStore, time() + $this->geoIpHelperCustomer->getCookieLifetime());
            setcookie('geoip_test_0', '4', time() + 100);
            setcookie('store', $requestStore, time() + 86400);


        return;
    }
}
```

Observer:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="custom_storeswitcher_observer_autoswitcher"
              instance="Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Observer\Autoswitcher"
    />
</event>
```

Observer Class:

```
class Autoswitcher implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer
     */
    protected $geoipHelperCustomer;

    /**
     * @var \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher
     */
    protected $modelSwitcher;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    protected $design;


    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer $geoipHelperCustomer
     * @param \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher $modelSwitcher
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Companyname\Customredirect\Helper\Customer $geoipHelperCustomer,
        \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Switcher $modelSwitcher,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {

        $this->geoipHelperCustomer = $geoipHelperCustomer;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->design = $design;
        $this->modelSwitcher = $modelSwitcher;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Automatically switches store according to customer's location
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return \Companyname\Customredirect\Model\Observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        if (!$this->modelSwitcher->isAllowed()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $customerStoreCode = $this->modelSwitcher->getCustomerStoreCode();
        if (!$customerStoreCode) {
            return $this;
        }

        $storeCookie = $this->geoipHelperCustomer->getCookie('geoip_store_code');
        if (!$storeCookie || $this->request->getParam('geoip_country', false)) {

            return $this->doRedirect($observer, $customerStoreCode, true);
        } elseif ($requestStore = $this->request->getParam('___store', false)) {
            setcookie('geoip_store_code', $requestStore, time() + ($this->geoipHelperCustomer->getCookieLifetime()));
            setcookie('geoip_test_0', '1', time() + 100);
            setcookie('store', $requestStore, time() + ($this->geoipHelperCustomer->getCookieLifetime()));

        }

        return $this;
    }


    public function doRedirect($observer, $customerStoreCode, $changeCookie = false)
    {

        $request = $this->request;

        $this->setDesignTheme($customerStoreCode);

        setcookie('store', $customerStoreCode, time() + 86400);
        if ($changeCookie) {
            setcookie('geoip_test_0', '2', time() + 100);
            $this->geoipHelperCustomer->setCookie('geoip_store_code', $customerStoreCode);
        }

        if ($request->getFullActionName() != 'cms_index_index') {
            $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($customerStoreCode);
        }

        $redirectUrl = $this->modelSwitcher->getRedirectUrl($customerStoreCode);

        if ($redirectUrl) {
            return $observer->getControllerAction()
                            ->getResponse()
                            ->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
        }

        return true;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following event which work when FPC enabled:

```
controller_front_send_response_before
```

or you can go with JS implementation.

Comment: Will it work with controller FrontControllerInterface beforeDispatch() method?

Comment: no, all are cached. After clear cache will call one time.

Comment: Event controller_front_send_response_before worked for me.